# difference of at least 4 between two numbers

Tags: permutations

In how many ways we can select two numbers from first $10$ natural numbers so that difference between them is at least four?

If we select the numbers from the interval $[1,10]$, will the answer change?  Here $[1,10]$ means the interval containing all real numbers from $1$ to $10$.  I have tried it using geometrical probability.

Comment: Is 6 - 10 valid ?

Comment: What do you mean by length[0,10]?

Comment: $10$ ways to choose the first number, $6$ ways to choose the second number.

Comment: @barakmanos only if we consider absolute value.

Comment: @barakmanos there should be less than $6$ ways to choose the second one, like if I start with $5$

Comment: (5,9) and (9,5) selections are same.right?

Comment: You should provide more explanations (what's the length [1,10]? Is it "the natural numbers from 1 to 10" as opposed to "the natural numbers from 0 to 9"?) and also how you tried to solve this. Otherwise, it just smells of "I have this exercise for school, anyone wants to do it for me?", sorry.

Comment: @polettix how can 0 be a natural number?

Comment: Thanks everyone..here [0,10] means interval containing all real number from 1 to 10.i have tried it using geometrical probability

Comment: There are uncountably many real numbers in the open interval between the two chosen numbers, so the answer definitely changes. Please check that I did not change the meaning of your post when I edited it. If you want to calculate the geometric probability that two real numbers selected from an interval of length 10 that includes the first ten natural numbers are at least four units apart, you may want $[0.5, 10.5]$ or $(0, 10]$.  I am leaving the left end of the interval $(0, 10]$ open since $0$ is considered to be a natural number by some mathematicians.

Comment: @Hailey I remember my Geometry professor telling us that the inclusion of 0 is somehow disputed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29 that states that "By most definitions 0 is a natural number". Which leads us to the Peano axioms, whose first one is "0 is a natural number" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), although "Today, some mathematicians prefer to replace "zero" by "one" in Peano's axioms" (https://books.google.it/books?id=7xArILpcndYC&pg=PA255&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). So... that's why I was asking!

Answer (score 3):

There are ambiguities in your question, as many have pointed out.

I am working out a way for natural #s $1$ thru $10$, you can easily adapt it to whatever you had in mind.

Take $7$ unnumbered balls, and a **block** of $3$ balls.

Choose any two from the seven unnumbered balls in $\binom72 = 21$ ways,
insert the block of $3$ immediately after the *leftmost* of the two chosen balls,
now number the balls serially.

All such configurations will satisfy the stipulations, thus ans $=\fbox{21}$

Comment: A suggestion:  Since you are numbering the balls after you select them, it would make more sense to say insert the block of $3$ after the leftmost of the two chosen balls.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig's suggestion, one word changed.

Comment: I was also suggesting that you change chosen numbers to chosen balls since you number the balls after you select them.

Comment: Despite my nitpicking, I like your argument. (+1)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:Thanks, done.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: You were quite right, the wording was loose. I was in a hurry for lunch !